# Trying to sort highest grade to lowest with entire struct

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, struct, typedef

I made a typdef struct of students it features: student ID , ClassId, currentGrade , and lettergrade.

Now I want to sort highest to lowest grade. I already done that but the other parts of struct are not sorted with it. How do I go about making the struct stay together with the sorting?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    short id;
    short enrolledClassID;
    float currentGrade;
    char letterGrade;
} Student;


void printStudentInfo(Student student);

void printStudentArray(Student* student,int sizeOfArray);

void sortByGrade(Student* student,int sizeOfArray);


int main() 
{
    Student studentArray[5] = {
        {25,278,95,'A'},
        { 27,278,56,'F' },
        { 29,321,74,'C' },
        { 31,321,63,'D' },
        { 15,278,81,'B' }
    };
    Student* pStudents = &studentArray;
    printStudentArray(pStudents,5); 
    sortByGrade(pStudents, 5);

    printStudentArray(pStudents, 5);
    //studentArray[0].currentGrade;
    system("Pause");
}

void sortByGrade(Student* student, int sizeOfArray) {
    int min, i;
    Student temp;
    while (sizeOfArray > 0)
    {
        min = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
            if (student[i].currentGrade < student[min].currentGrade)
                min = i;
        temp.currentGrade = student[sizeOfArray - 1].currentGrade;
        student[sizeOfArray - 1].currentGrade =         student[min].currentGrade;
        student[min].currentGrade = temp.currentGrade;
        sizeOfArray--;
    }

}

void printStudentInfo(Student student) {
    printf("The student ID is %i, class ID is %i, current grade in class is %0.2f\n, and letter grade is %c\n", student.id, student.enrolledClassID,student.currentGrade,student.letterGrade);
}

void printStudentArray(Student* student,int sizeOfArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++) {
        printStudentInfo(student[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: When swapping, copy the struct not just the .currentGrade struct member.  Also, any reason not to use `qsort()`?

Comment: I am confused on with qsort on how to use it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only moving around the current grade, not the entire structure.  So instead of this:

```
temp.currentGrade = student[sizeOfArray - 1].currentGrade;
student[sizeOfArray - 1].currentGrade = student[min].currentGrade;
student[min].currentGrade = temp.currentGrade;
```

Do this:

```
temp= student[sizeOfArray - 1];
student[sizeOfArray - 1] = student[min];
student[min] = temp;
```

Comment: Thank you I am new to structs.

Comment: @rev2k9 Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Using [qsort()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html) to sort your array is not difficult. The first argument is the array itself, the second is the number of elements in the array, the third is the size of each array element (`sizeof (Student)`), and the fourth is a function pointer that returns -1 if the compared to elements are in the correct order, 0 if equal, and +1 if in the wrong order.

So:

```
int compareByGrade(const void *ptr1, const void *ptr2)
{
    const Student *const s1 = ptr1;
    const Student *const s2 = ptr2;

    if (s1->currentGrade > s2->currentGrade)
        return -1; /* Correct order */
    else
    if (s1->currentGrade < s2->currentGrade)
        return +1; /* Wrong order */
    else
        return  0; /* Same grade */
}
```

although I personally like to rewrite that as

```
int compareByGrade(const void *ptr1, const void *ptr2)
{
    const float val1 = ((const Student *)ptr1)->currentGrade;
    const float val2 = ((const Student *)ptr2)->currentGrade;
    return (val1 > val2) ? -1 : (val1 < val2) ? +1 : 0;
}
```

which does the exact same thing, but with more concise expressions. Use the one you find easier to read, understand, and maintain (in the long term).

In both cases, the `sortByGrade()` function is just

```
void sortByGrade(Student *const array, const size_t elements)
{
    if (array != NULL && elements > 1)
        qsort(array, elements, sizeof array[0], compareByGrade);
}
```

Note that you should use `size_t` type for nonnegative memory sizes -- `size_t` is usually unsigned (cannot represent negative values) --, things like number of elements in array, array indices, string lengths, and so on. It is the purpose of the type.

On current 64-bit architectures, `int` is only 32-bit, so if you get into the habit of using `int` for memory sizes, your code will only be able to reference just 2 GB of memory. This is a real problem with old programs, because their programmers didn't think it'd ever be a problem. (It is so bad, actually, that the Linux kernel had to restrict writes to files to less than 2GB at a time.)

So, please, become better than those problematic old-timey programmers, and learn how to use `size_t` instead of `unsigned int` or `int`.